# Unhandled promise rejection using sendgrid and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I am new to these languages, I'm working on a project that provides a management of a database of users and a function for each of them, by button, to send them emails with their code.
I'm using *nodejs*, *expressjs* (database) and *sendgrid*, these are their versions (I think they are the last ones):

> "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.2.1",
>   "sendgrid-rest": "^2.4.0",
>   "express": "^4.16.2",
>   node v8.9.4

I am using *windows 10* and through the official sengrid guides I have obtained the following code:

```
exports.sendMail = function(req,res){

var name = req.params.nome;
var email = req.params.email;
var code = req.params.code;

const  sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey('api_key');
const  msg = {
  to: email,
  from: 'a@b.com',
  subject: 'event',
  text: 'Dear '+name+',\n'+'this is your code: \n',
  html: '<br><strong>'+code+'</strong><br>',
};
sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
    res.redirect('/users');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
});

}
```

I tried creating an environment variable via windows settings, but it did not work. I found another solution that proposed to create a **.env** file and to export a variable containing the api_key of sendgrid:

```
export SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'SG.xxx...'
```

but for the time being it does not seem to work, rather I receive these messages, and no e-mails are sent.
I checked the correctness of the api_key and it's the one that starts with SG.XXXXX... , so I think it's right.
Here are the messages:

```
(node:9688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Provide at least one of to, cc or bcc
(node:9688) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

They are simple warnings, but I fear they affect the operation.

Another question: I read in some posts, that the use of api_key in a file in the project directory (I think they spoke of the public directory (/ project / public)), I put the file in the main directory of my project (/ project), has security problems because it could be seen externally, is it safe what I did? Do I have to move it to other directories?

Every help is welcome, I thought it would be much easier to use the sendgrid service in a web app.If there was a faster method through sendgrid it is welcome.

**EDIT:** Thanks to the answers I managed to arrive in part to a solution, modifying the code as above, I do not receive any error but it seems not to send any email to the mailbox. Some help?

Comment: I think the `send` function returns a `promise` so just add one `.catch` statement and the problem will be solved. And this will let you know why `send()` is failing

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had read something about it in some forums, but why not write it in the official documentation? As they are warning, the code should do the same, but apparently it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this, You are not handling the error condition. `Error: Provide at least one of to, cc or bcc` may be **to email** is null/undefined.

```
sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
    res.redirect('/users');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, done, but now I'm getting an error like:
*error Error: Provide at least one of to, cc or bcc ... users.js: 126: 12*
in the code that sends the email:
*sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {*
something wrong

Comment: value of email might be null `to: email`, print email and see what are you getting.

Comment: Thank! I solved this part, I just do this: *to: '\''+email+'\''*, But now I'm getting an authorization error, I think about my api_key, I tried to directly insert my api_key in the method like this:*sgMail.setApiKey('SG.xxx');* but now the error is like this: *code: 400, message: 'Bad Request'*. Thank for your help.

Comment: Ok is solved, thank so much, i think params are null. I'm try to solve this.